# PS Plus subscription

Tags: ps4, psn

I have created a new account on my PS4 but I want my main account Playstation plus to share with the new one, can someone tell me how I looked at a similar question but didn't tell me how.

Comment: Next time, please do not bold the entire body of your post.

Comment: Why does this bother you

Comment: @Nathan, it is considered bad formatting. One of the reasons you might attract downvotes.

Comment: Because bold is for emphasis, so it is pointless to bold **everything**

Answer (score 0):

From your 'main' account which has PSN already, you need to set this PS4 to your 'primary' PS4.

This will then share the PSN access with all accounts on this console.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, if this has answered your question then please click the 'tick' accepting it. Thanks :)